# Check entire project for runtime errors

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, webforms, migration, runtime-error

We are in the process of migrating from an older server to a newer server. We have a VERY large project (primarily web forms) that will be making the move, and would like to be able to check each page in the project for runtime errors without having to actually navigate to each and every page and doing a visual inspection.

To clarify, we want to identify if there are pages after the migration that are going to display that horrible yellow screen, for reasons such as out of memory, reference not found, or any of the other many issues that could come with a migration.

Has anyone done this before? Is there some sort of open source solution for this?

Comment: Do you have any end-to-end tests that you can use? Typically you would develop tests as you write the code and then you can check that everything continues to work with each update to the system. To add tests to a running system is quite tedious though.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It's an older project that I was put on and there are no existing tests.

Comment: I would use the same tools though, look into selenium and webdriver which provides a way to automate a browser. Then as long as you can provide a list of pages to visit you can make the browser go to each page and verify that it loaded correctly.

Comment: The new Visual Studio Online has some good testing options.  If you are using Microsoft for Source Code they can even be automated or included as a check prior to deployment.